In the QFT, do the basis states $\{|k\pmod N\rangle\}_{k=0}^N$ only make sense when $N=2^n$?
When I started learning quantum computing, I learned that for an $n$ qubit system, the basis states look like $$ \bigg\{ |\text{n-bit strings}\rangle\bigg\}\,.$$ So an $n$ qubit system has $2^n$ basis states.
But then, learning about the quantum Fourier transform, basis states now look like $$\bigg\{\big|k\, (\text{mod} N)\big\rangle\bigg\}_{k = 0,\cdots,N}\,.$$ This only makes sense when $N$ is a power of two right? Otherwise, I don't see the connection between the two representations.

Note that you can simply map each of the $N$ possible values to distinct bit strings. Is this sufficient to resolve your issue? Welcome to the stack exchange.

You can define the Fourier transform on any dimension $D$ as
$$
|k\rangle\longrightarrow |\tilde k\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{D}}\sum_{j=0}^{D-1}e^{i2\pi jk/D}|j\rangle.
$$
This means that you've got a $D\times D$ unitary
$$
U_D=\sum_{k=0}^{D-1}|\tilde k\rangle\langle k|.
$$
Where it gets more messy is if you want to embed this into a set of $n$ qubits such that $N=2^n\geq D$. You basically have to extend the space, perhaps something like
$$
|k\rangle\longrightarrow\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
|\tilde k\rangle & 0\leq k<D \\
|k\rangle & D\leq k<N.
\end{array}\right.
$$
However, while you can always define it like this, this next question is whether we can implement it efficiently. The standard solution for the quantum Fourier transform relies on the very special case $N=D$.

No, You can also display just 2 different states with arbitrarily many qubits (i.e. $N=1$). Of course, $N\leq 2^n$ so that You can represent all states.
Basically, the states $2^n\geq x>N$ when $N$ is not a power of two will have 0 amplitude.
Also for $|k \mod N\rangle$, $|0\rangle=|N\rangle$
